# Lift curve is swapped

Tags: r, r-caret

For the example for the lift curve I run

```
library(caret)
set.seed(1)
simulated <- data.frame(obs = factor(rep(letters[1:2], each = 100)),
                        perfect = sort(runif(200), decreasing = TRUE),
                        random = runif(200))
lift2 <- lift(obs ~ random + perfect, data = simulated)
xyplot(lift2, plot = "lift", auto.key = list(columns = 2))
```

and get

[image]

as result. I expected the image to be swapped horizontally - something along the lines of

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Btw: This is a lift chart not a cumulative gains chart.

## Update:

The plot that I expected, produced now by my own code

```
mylift <- caret::lift(Class ~ cforest_prob + perfect_prob + guess_prob, data = data_test)
ggplot(mylift$data) +
  geom_line(aes(CumTestedPct, lift, color = liftModelVar))
```

is

[image]

I noticed, that the data.frame `mylift$data` contains the following columns:

```
names(mylift$data)
 [1] "liftModelVar" "cuts"         "events"       "n"            "Sn"           "Sp"           "EventPct"    
 [8] "CumEventPct"  "lift"         "CumTestedPct"
```

So I printed the following plot

```
ggplot(mylift$data) +
  geom_line(aes(cuts, lift, color = liftModelVar))
```

[image]

So I guess that the different plots are just different ways of examining lift? I wasn't aware that there are different lift charts - I thought it was standardized across the industry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit by the question author, for late readers*: I accepted this answer for a large part because of the helpful discussion in the comments to this answer. Please consider reading the discussion!

---

Let's reproduce the graph and find the baseline. Let

```
cutoffs <- seq(0, 1, length = 1000)
```

be our cutoffs. Now the main computations are done by

```
aux <- sapply(cutoffs, function(ct) {
  perf <- simulated$obs[simulated$perfect > ct]
  rand <- simulated$obs[simulated$random > ct]
  c(mean(perf == "a"), mean(rand == "a"))
})
```

where we go over the vector of cutoffs and do the following. Take the `perfect` case. We say that whenever `perfect > ct`, we are going to predict `"a"`. Then `simulated$obs[simulated$perfect > ct]` are the true values, while `mean(perf == "a")` is our accuracy with a given cutoff. The same happens with `random`.

As for the baseline, it is just a constant defined by the share of `"a"` in the sample:

```
baseline <- mean(simulated$obs == "a")
```

When plotting the lifts, we divide our accuracy by that of the baseline method and get the same graph along with the baseline curve:

```
plot(x = cutoffs, y = aux[1, ] / baseline, type = 'l', ylim = c(0, 2), xlab = "Cutoff", ylab = "Lift")
lines(x = cutoffs, y = aux[2, ] / baseline, col = 'blue')
abline(a = baseline / baseline, b = 0, col = 'magenta')
```

[image]

**Update**:

Here's an illustration that, at least when plotted manually, the lift curve of the "expected" type can be manipulated and gives non-unique results.

Your example graph is from [here](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~dbd/cs831/notes/lift_chart/lift_chart.html), which also has this data:

```
#   contacted response
# 1      10000     6000
# 2      20000    10000
# 3      30000    13000
# 4      40000    15800
# 5      50000    17000
# 6      60000    18000
# 7      70000    18800
# 8      80000    19400
# 9      90000    19800
# 10    100000    20000
```

Now suppose that we know not this evolution but 10 individual blocks:

```
#    contacted response
# 1      10000     6000
# 2      10000     4000
# 3      10000     3000
# 4      10000     2800
# 5      10000     1200
# 6      10000     1000
# 7      10000      800
# 8      10000      600
# 9      10000      400
# 10     10000      200
```

In that case it depends on how we order the observations when putting "% Contacted" in the x-axis:

```
set.seed(1)
baseline <- sum(df$response) / sum(df$contacted) * cumsum(df$contacted)
lift1 <- cumsum(df$response)
lift2 <- cumsum(sample(df$response))
x <- 1:10 * 10

plot(x = x, y = lift1 / baseline, col = 'red', type = 'l', ylim = c(0, 3), xlab = "% Customers contacted", ylab = "Lift")
lines(x = x, y = lift2 / baseline, col = 'blue')
abline(a = baseline / baseline, b = 0, col = 'magenta')
```

[image]

Comment: (You mixed up the labels.) So what you are saying is that the graph is correct? Is it because "cut-off"means something different than "% Customers Contacted"? Can you elaborate on the theoretical aspects?

Comment: @Make42, thanks, fixed the graph. What do you mean by "graph is correct"? It does what it does. Actually this is the first time I hear about this lift graph, but it is sensible what it does in terms of classification models, and yes, it correctly works with your examle data. In terms of the baseline, it will always be at y=1, so it is somewhat redundant, and perhaps not plotted for this reason...

Comment: ...As for your [example](http://www2.cs.uregina.ca/~dbd/cs831/notes/lift_chart/lift_chart.html), it is indeed very different.. Of course, 2 classes here can be related to response/no response, but then also, for instance, we look at >cutoff and <% customers contacted, your example above is with individual observations, while the linked ones is aggregate. If you are dealing with classification models, I think it's only confusing to bring it up. Both of your graphs are good for their purpose, _only the name is the same_. That shouldn't be a problem.. So, just plot what is needed in your case.

Comment: I plotted the "expected" plot for my own data and updated my post. I guess that there are different "lift charts" and it is not uniformly defined across the industry how it has to look like (unlike ROC charts, as it seems)?

Comment: @Make42, I think to me it makes sense that your expected plot isn't the default one: you have `CumTestedPct` in the x-axis, which is not unambiguous. That is, you may test your cases in whatever order, and the curve would be different. Meanwhile, nothing like this can be done with thresholds. Now if there is some sort of unique order of the observations, then I guess your expected plot also makes sense. As long as it's clear what is in the x-axis, I really think it doesn't matter how common the plot is.. after all, there will always be the same lift on the y-axis.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. I disagree with the ordering: If I go with the "expected" graph, for each of the curves, I need to order the observations (here we agree). But if you use a cut-off, you intrinsically also order the observations and chose all those that are larger than the cut-off (here we disagree).

Comment: @Make42, with cutoffs you do somehow also get this `CumTestedPct` where the order seems to matter (or maybe not), but in my answer I only have, say, `simulated$obs[simulated$perfect > ct]` where the order of the observations doesn't matter. Then yes, picking different cutoffs will choose only a subset of the observations, but the user cannot do anything about all this. Unless I'm misunderstanding something, I mean that a user can manipulate and cheat with the "expected" graph unless there is a meaning in the order, and it cannot be done with cutoffs.

Comment: I don't think you can "cheat". You basically take the x%-largest values of the probability per model/curve. There is no way of cheating.

Comment: @Make42, see the update where I added an example of what I meant. Clearly it may be that with `CumTestedPct` one cannot cheat because of how `lift` computes this `CumTestedPct`. Or, as you say, if there is certain fixed order: x%-largest values... To me it's not obvious that it is the standard choice. If it is, then indeed there are no problems.

Comment: I see what you mean. I understood it differently: Our table has a column for each trained model. The values are the model's probabilities that the person (row) will respond. For each model: We initialize the cut-off with 1.0. Now we decrease the cut-off step-wise (e.g. by 0.05). People with a probability higher than the cut-off are going to be contacted. For each step, the lift is the number of people that respond more, compared to the previous step. So, the lift says how many people will be reached more - improvement of the situation (but with the added cost of having to contact more people).

Comment: @Make42, that indeed makes sense and there's no cheating. My idea was simply that "% Customers Contacted" alone is a little too vague and seeing it in some random presentation I'd be suspicious, but perhaps your outlined strategy is indeed a common knowledge.